# Excel 2003: is it possible to create a table only if a cell exists?

Tags: excel

If I have two columns A and B.  A contains text strings and B will have either Yes or No.

Is there a way to create a new column or table C that only shows the text strings from A where the associated cell in B is Yes?

Comment: `=IF(B1="Yes",A1,"")`?

Comment: Yes that would work, but I then have some cells that are empty.  Is there a way to only show cells that have a value and ignore empty ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in `C1`

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$11="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1))
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag it down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  first cell works But I just get #NUM! when I copy it to the others

Comment: 1) do you really have `Yes` in column `B` 2) if yes, try `=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$11)="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1))` - it seems that your values in col B contains trailing/leading spaces

Comment: @Ruf1, it returns `#NUM!` if if all the values with `Yes` ​​are over. If you don't want return `#NUM`, you can modify formula to return empty string or some message like follows: `=IFERROR(=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$11)="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C‌​$1)+1)),"Stop! Values are over!")`

Comment: its definitely Yes.  Should I formate the cell in a certain way to remove spaces?  I tried your second code, but says there's an error in the code and the editor hilights $c$1

Comment: Formula without error handling: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$11)="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1))`, formula with error handling: `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$11)="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1))),"Stop! Values are over!",INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$11)="Yes",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1)))`. See my test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuivhk93ts7088a/Book1.xls .

Comment: P.S. if formulas gives you error and highlights `$C‌​$1`, try to remove `$C$1` and retype it again (or better download my workbook with working formula). For some reason SO changed `C` character to another one with similar spelling and Excel doesn't recognize it

Comment: How do I do this if the table data does start until say row 9?

Comment: if table starts from row 9, use this one in `C9`: `=INDEX($A$9:$A$20,SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$9:$B$20)="Yes",ROW($A$9:$A$20)),ROW()-ROW($C‌​$9)+1))`